# PHP Fast CGI on mac osx - phpfcgi.plist not runing by load, not runing by reboot neither

Tags: php, macos, nginx, launchd, launchdagent

I have loaded phpcgi.plist but php-fastcgi is not runing.

The plist file is:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:~ michael$ ll com*
-rwxr--r--  1 michael  admin  664  4  7 13:40 com.phpfcgi.plist*
```

The plist XML:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:~ michael$ cat com.phpfcgi.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Debug</key>
  <false/>
  <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
  <dict>
    <key>PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS</key>
    <string>1000</string>
  </dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.phpfcgi</string>
  <key>OnDemand</key>
  <false/>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/php-cgi</string>
    <string>-b 127.0.0.1:9000</string>
    <string>-q</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Linked it:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:~ michael$ ll Library/LaunchAgents/com.phpfcgi.plist
lrwxr-xr-x  1 michael  admin  47  4  7 13:27 Library/LaunchAgents/com.phpfcgi.plist@ -> /Volumes/MainHD/Users/michael/com.phpfcgi.plist
```

and I load it:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:~ michael$ launchctl load -w Library/LaunchAgents/com.phpfcgi.plist
com.phpfcgi: Already loaded
```

and I check it:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:~ michael$ ps -A | grep php
 1110 ttys000    0:00.00 grep php
```

NOT WORKING.

But I can start php fastcgi by run.

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:~ michael$ cat start_php-fastcgi
/usr/local/bin/php-cgi -q -b 127.0.0.1:9000 &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**should no space between "-b" and the host** (my system is osx 10.8)

I found a comment:

Thank you for this plist file! A lot of the tutorials show a space between "-b" and the host name and port. My process kept dying with a status of 255, until I removed that space. – Matt Aug 26 '12 at 16:24

from [OS X: Auto start PHP FCGI via launchd on system start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741365/os-x-auto-start-php-fcgi-via-launchd-on-system-start)

It solved my problem.

The new plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
  <dict>
    <key>PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS</key>
    <string>1000</string>
  </dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.phpfcgi</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/php54/bin/php-cgi</string>
    <string>-b127.0.0.1:9000</string>
    <string>-q</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: A space is ok on the command line, because the shell treats spaces as separators between arguments, and php-cgi will understand when "-b" and the host are passed as separate arguments. But in a launchd .plist, if you include a space in a string element of the ProgramArguments array, it's treated as part of the argument. So for launchd, either remove the space, or list -b and the host as separate strings.

Comment: BTW: I removed the debug section, I think it's not the point for me. I just want to run php in Nginx for develop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between loading and starting a job. Your job definition does not contain a run condition. You specified `RunAtLoad false`, telling `launchd(8)` to not run the job when it is loaded. If you did this on purpose you can run the job with `launchctl start com.phpfcgi`.

Comment: Michaels-MacBook-Pro:~ michael$ launchctl list | grep php
- 255 com.phpfcgi